# simple form add class to surrounding div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm writing a custom wrapper for simple form:

```
## Inputs
b.wrapper tag: :div, class: 'col-lg-4 input-group' do |component|
  component.use :input, class: 'form-control'
  component.wrapper tag: :span, class: 'input-group-addon' do |icon|
    icon.wrapper :icon, tag: :i do
    end
  end
end
```

The generates the HTML:

```
<div class="string optional q_post_date_gteq">
 <div class="col-lg-4 input-group">
  <input class="string optional datepicker form-control" placeholder="Start" type="text" name="q[post_date_gteq]" id="q_post_date_gteq">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
 </div>
</div>
```

The `<div class="string optional q_post_date_gteq">` seems to be autogenerated. I want to add a class to it, how is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried passing this option to `f.input` - `wrapper_html: { class: 'your-class' } }`

Comment: You can also do when you define: `config.wrappers :your_wrapper_name, class: 'your-class' do |b| ...` See [docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Custom-Wrappers)

Comment: @PetrGazarov thanks! could you write an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple form generates a wrapper div around the input and label by default. There are two ways that I know of to configure html options for your custom wrapper.

**1. You can pass `wrapper_html` option to the form builder in your template:**

```
f.input :some_property_name, wrapper_html: { class: 'your-class' }
```

**2. Pass class option to `wrappers` when defining custom wrapper:**

```
config.wrappers :your_wrapper_name, class: 'your-class' do |b| ...
```

There are some great docs about defining custom wrappers in case you need any more help! https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Custom-Wrappers

Comment: I always forgot about that `wrapper_html` attribute on the input, and I always come back to this answer. :D

Answer (score -3):

If you can't find an answer using only ruby, this could do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".q_post_date_gteq").addClass("...");
});
```

EDIT:

To answer to comments: add a "wrapper" so you have something like this

```
<div class="simple-form-wrapper">
    <div class="string optional q_post_date_gteq">
     <div class="col-lg-4 input-group">
      <input class="string optional datepicker form-control" placeholder="Start" type="text" name="q[post_date_gteq]" id="q_post_date_gteq">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And now, the jQuery part becomes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".simple-form-wrapper").children.first.addClass("...");
});
```

Comment: That's a good idea. I'd like to know the ruby way but this will work if all else fails. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is robust. There is no documentation about this class, so I wouldn't be surprised if it changes dynamically or in next release.

Comment: @PetrGazarov I've edited my answer, it should work no matter the changes